# Any Bubble Earth Map Text Color Change

Tags: javascript, maps, bubble-chart, anychart

I am using anychart for drawing map, I need to change the color of country names as given in screenshot
I tried several ways by changing it from map properties but it not helping I am able to change all other colors except text.

Please let me know which properties should I edit to make the color change

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should apply [fontColor()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.ui.LabelsFactory.Label#fontColor) setting to the series or chart labels. For details, check the snippet below:

```
  var labels = map.labels();
  labels.enabled(true).fontColor('red');
```